# Setting an ImageView from a For-Loop

Tags: java, android, input, imageview

This question may be a bit a tricky.  I tried, but I am not really even sure what to search for, so I did not find any documentation on this.

I have a 7x10 grid, and each grid has its own image view.  The ImageViews for the grids are named grid00, grid01, ..., grid79, grid710.  I want to change the image for each grid in a nested for loop. so where it says in my code:

```
grid04.setImageResource(R.drawable.walllr);
```

What I realy want it to do is:

```
gridij.setImageResource(R.drawable.walllr);
```

where *i* and *j* after the word grid are the *i* and *j* from the nested for loop.

I am trying to change the image for all 70 items without writing code for each of the 70 items.  Is this possible?  Here is the code:

```
public void initialize() {
    map = DM.getMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (map[i][j].isUsed()) {
                grid04.setImageResource(R.drawable.walllr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just through that in there as a test to make sure it was replacing the image. grid04 is the name of one of my ImageViews

Comment: so your problem belongs with saving grids in bidimensional arrays?

Comment: (There are 70 ImageViews ranging from grid00 to grid710)

Comment: no my problem is that I want to change all 70 ImageViews in a for loop. You can consider the code just to be a single for loop.  I want to replace "04" with whatever is in my forloop

Comment: If you want to do that you need 2d arrays

Comment: I dont think you are understanding the question. If you look at my code, you can see that i AM using a 2D array

Comment: I think you don't understand that your code is simply wrong. Calling grids grid04 or so is so bad Java would cry. You need 2D arrays (not the one you are using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array of ImageViews.

```
Imageview[] myImageViewArray = new ImageView[70];
int imageViewCounter=0;

and in your function

public void initialize() {
    map = DM.getMap();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (map[i][j].isUsed()) {
                myImageViewArray[imageViewCounter]=new ImageView();
                myImageViewArray[imageViewCounter].setImageResource(R.drawable.walllr);
                imageViewCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this way. But you should modify it before you use for your function. Hope this helps.

Comment: i ended up using a combination of everyones code, but your code best helped me get there. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention where are those `ImageViews` named `gridxx`. If `gridxx` represents the id of that `ImageView` in the xml layout then you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if (map[i][j].isUsed()) {
            int id = getIdentifier("grid" + i + j, "id", getPackageName()); 
            ((ImageView)findViewById(id)).setImageResource(R.drawable.walllr);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `getIdentifier()` method is a bit slow.
If for some odd reason, those are names used in the java class, the solution is to use an array like normal people.

Comment: @Evorlor From your question is not clear how you use those `ImageViews`, if you declare them in the xml layout or you add them in code. If it's the first version then use the code in my answer. If it's the second option then, when you create the `ImageView`, create an array to hold references to them.

Comment: You're gonna have a tough time programming if you don't know what arrays are. Read about them here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Imageview[][] grid = new Imageview[7][10];
for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)   
        for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) //from 0 to 10, dunno if you want it from 1 to 10
         {
           grid[i][j]=new Imageview(....)
         }
```

This is the only way to change all grids, like you want to do. First, create the grids. They will no longer be called `grid04` or so, but `grid[0][4].`

Answer (score 0):

Create an 2D array of ImageView[7][10].

Comment: can you be more specific please? I do not understand